# CSS first-child and overflow

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem with not working "first-child". I want to make top of christmas tree as red so first div.main have to be div with red background.

And another problem is that if I set amount of the height of this tree over 70 the next char is in next line but want to stay this div in line over and scroll it in this case.

Sorry for not English name of Variables

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.center {
border:2px solid black;
display:block;
}

div.main{
display:inline-block;
color:green;
}

div.main:first-child {
    background-color:red
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="choinka.php" method="GET">
wysokość: <input type="text" name="tak">
<input type="submit" value="dawaj">
</form>


<?php
$tak = $_GET['tak'];
echo " wysokosc to: $tak";
echo '<div class="center>";
for($wysokosc = $_GET['tak']; $wysokosc >=  0;$wysokosc--){
echo "<br>";
for($szerokosc = 0; $szerokosc <= $wysokosc ; $szerokosc++){
echo "&#8195"; //spacja szerokosc 1em 
if($szerokosc == $wysokosc) 
    for($znaki = $_GET['tak'];  $znaki >= $wysokosc ; $znaki--){
        echo '<div class="main">&#8195  &#8855</div>';
    }
}
};
echo "</div><br><br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try `div.main:first-of-type` instead of `div.main:first-child` as you can see loop append a `<br></br>` before `main` and `:first-child` get `<br>` as the first child.
This will do the trick [Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5UEa.png)

Comment: Don't mention that bro. Please Select The answer for others help.